# Inheriting Child Methods

Tags: php, inheritance

Okay I want to know if a parent class in PHP can access or "inherit" methods from a child or "extended" class. For example, if I have a parent class with a method called `foo` and the child class has a method called `bar` can I call `bar` from `foo`?

Question 2: Say I have a parent class called "actions" and it has a single method called "perform" which took the argument "foo" as a string. Then we have two seperate classes called "actionA" and "actionB" respectively. Each child class contains a method called "method-"className"", if possible how would I go about calling a child method based on the argument provided to the "perform" method in the "actions" class?

Comment: You can call `bar()` from `foo()` using `static::bar()`: [late static binding](http://uk3.php.net/lsb) but it isn't a case of a parent inheriting from a child, but of an instantiated child having both methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

No, because that way the parent class could not work on its own.

Yes, because PHP offers a construct for that: abstract classes. An abstract class cannot be instantiated itself but other classes can inherit from it. Abstract methods within an abstract class do not have to have a body and *must* be implemented by any non-abstract child class (like an interface).

Well, let the code speak:

```
<?php

// note the "abstract" keyword
abstract class ParentClass {

    public function foo() {
        $this->bar();
    }

    // again, note the "abstract" keyword and note how the method does
    // not have a body (i.e. not any actual code)
    abstract public function bar();
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    public function bar() {
        echo 'bar called!';
    }

}

$foo = new ParentClass(); // this will raise an error
$bar = new ChildClass(); // this will work
$bar->foo(); // this will echo "bar called!"
$bar->bar(); // ... as will this

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent can call `public` and `protected` methods of the child class, but not `private` methods.